# Braintree Credential Validation Failed in Magento 2.4.5

Tags: braintree, magento2.4.5

Facing Braintree Credential Validation Failed When I try to add new API key values in configurations.

So please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the issue you are facing? So I can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but now it is resolved.

Comment: Hi @DhirendrasinhRathod even I am facing same issue, how did you resolve it?

Comment: can you please share your error?